# Infer TypeScript generic class type

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-statements, type-inference

B extends a generic class A. I need to be able to infer the generic type of the extended A of B. See code below.

I used this in previous Typescript versions successfully but for my current project using 3.2.4 (also tried latest 3.4.5) the inferred type seems to result in `{}` instead of `string`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? This can't possibly have changed?

```js
class A<T> {

}

class B extends A<string> {

}

type GenericOf<T> = T extends A<infer X> ? X : never;

type t = GenericOf<B>; // results in {}, expected string
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently a class who has a generic that isn't used in the class literally has the same "structure" as `{}` hence the inference. The change that was made that broke your functionality was a bug fix and the workaround is to use "A's" generic somewhere inside the class and the inference will work again.

Hope this helps.

```
class A<T> {
    hello: T = "" as any; // note that i have used the generic somewhere in the class body.
}
class B extends A<string> {}
type GenericOf<T> = T extends A<infer X> ? X : never;
type t = GenericOf<B>; // string.
```

Comment: `hello: T = "" as any; // note that i have used the generic somewhere in the class body.`

Your comment really help me with my problem. Looks like TS doesn't try to inferring types of generic if they aren't used

Answer (score 0):

Alright nvm figured it out myself after tons of research. Seems TypeScript isn't able to differentiate in this simple case because those classes are all empty and equivalent to `{}`. Adding properties isn't actually enough, it needs to be properties that actually reference the generic `T` in order for TypeScript to correctly infer the generic type later on:

```js
class A<T> {
  constructor(public a: T) {}
}

class B extends A<C> {
  constructor(public b: C) {
    super(b);
  }
}

class C {
  constructor(public c: string) {
  }
}

type GenericOf<T> = T extends A<infer X> ? X : never;

type t = GenericOf<B>;
```