# Constructor as parameter: infer class's generic into function

Tags: typescript

How to make the typescript compiler infer the right type in this example?

```
interface A<T> {
  do(param: T): void
}

class A2 implements A<string>{
  do(param){}
}

function createA<T>(constr: new () => A<T>, param: T){}

createA(A2, "")
```

Here it won't compile and T is inferred the type any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the class generic as well so that you can tell typescript the interface parameter and the function argument are of the same type, without repeating yourself:

```
class A2<T extends string> implements A<T>{
  go(param: T) {
     param.split('') // string method is allowed here
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIB4AqA+ZBvAKGWQHMB7ACgAc4o4BbALmUwEpmA3M4AEwIF8CBBABs4AZ3FoATFmQQAHpBA8p4sFFAlcwelRER6EcFIw5CxctVoNmbfEWLIadegDpx+4GAoByX6zIAPRByOqaICTIRmAAFmQ8yMBScCIiZADuEImx0BCOgoIEMACuIAhgwGQgyAhQEHCQZtgUCNXhzCAQGcgUgQC8uM0ANM42TCyseEV1DU0UqNKjAETLrEA)

Comment: So it's some kind of limitation? Because I would expect the type of **param** inside the function **go** to be inferred as string, without having to re-declare it for every method that uses T. Is there another way to achieve the same result but without having to declare the signature of methods every time? I mean, it's still typesafe because it will give you an error if you place the wrong type but it's reduntant.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't infer it properly. I agree that it seems like it should. But when typescript fails to infer something, there's usually some creative usage of generics that get it to do the right thing.

Comment: maybe somehow related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886792/infer-typescript-generic-class-type `Currently a class who has a generic that isn't used in the class literally has the same "structure" as {} hence the inference`

Comment: My best guess is that a class implementing an interface is never used for inference, but simply for validating that the interface is implemented correctly. See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnICYD2AFAA5xRwC2AXMgM5hSgDmAlLQG4HB5YC+WLAgA2cOnTQAmZMEolhEShHATU2XLkKlyVVphwbcBgXyA) for simpler case

Comment: Also, i just figured out that without classes it works just right [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=22#code/C4TwDgpgBAggPAFQHxQLxQN4HMD2AuKACjAEMAnEgWwIQEo0UA3HASwBMBfAKC4GMcAdgGdgUAMIwATGiK0C8DAA8CIsiwFYOKVCkIYuUKLgLF6OzAcNQwAOkWXuHWjy4AzAK4DewFoKi8yCBJgCHhkQn5hYDITMxQwpAAaa3IqGloMbj5A4NDCCUlkpQIAIhKnIA)

Comment: @rockson yes, I believe this lack of inference is specifically related to the `implements` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make it `do(param: string)` if you implement the `A<string>` interface with the `A2` Class.If you try to give it any other type you should get an error, for example if you use `do(param: number)` in `A<string>` implementation you get

```
Property 'do' in type 'A2' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'A<string>'.
  Type '(param: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(param: string) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'param' and 'param' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```