How to infer type of overloaded method in generic function?
I am trying to create a generic function that would subscribe to an event emitter. The subscribe function would accept 3 arguments: event name, event handler and the event emitter to attach to.
How to make it correctly infer type definitions, especially for the event handler, so when I pass, for example, process object as an event emitter and 'warning' as an event name, I would not have to explicitly declare handler arguments' types:
subscribe('warning', (warning) => {/* */}, process);
//                    ^
//                    the `warning` argument should have `Error` type as defined 
//                    in `process` interface:
//
//                    interface Process {
//                      ...
//                      addListener(event: "warning", listener: WarningListener): this;
//                    }
//                    ...
//
//                    type WarningListener = (warning: Error) => void;

Here is my implementation along with the example usage. However, it only works with the second event (event 'b', and not with event 'a').
interface Target<N, H> {
  on(name: N, handler: H): unknown;
}

const subscribe = <
  N extends T extends Target<infer N, unknown> ? N : never,
  H extends T extends Target<N, infer H> ? H : never,
  T extends Target<unknown, unknown>,
>(
  name: N,
  handler: H,
  target: T
) => {
  target.on(name, handler);
};

const target: {
  on(name: 'a', handler: (a1: string) => void): void;
  on(name: 'b', handler: (b1: number) => void): void;
} = {
  on: ()=>{},
};

// errors with: Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"b"'.
subscribe('a', (a1) => console.log(a1), target);


// works fine
subscribe('b', (b1) => console.log(b1), target); 


You can't do this. Inferring from overloads gives you only the last call signature as mentioned in the docs. Refactoring to fix this will end up radically changing your approach, since generics, conditional types, contextual typing, and overloads play very poorly together. You'd need something that looks like this playground link. Does this fully address your question (even if it's not to your liking)? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Thanks for the docs reference!
The playground you provided will however not solve my issue where I specifically wanted to have the callback arguments having the inferred type. In the mentioned playground it is still necessary to type the a1 and b1 arguments.

Sorry, I was trying to make it clear that what you’re asking for is not possible. My example refactoring wasn’t meant to solve your underlying use case so much as to show the kind of refactoring necessary to even express what you’re doing.  The answer, if I write one up, will target the question as asked, which is about overloaded function inference. Am I missing anything?

Thanks for the clarification! I wonder if it is even possible to make such a subscribe function that would infer the type of a callback, provided that the EventEmitter has, as in your example, a generic on<> method?

Not directly, in my experience. You’d need to refactor, maybe? You’re looking for a higher order inference than what TS supports. But this is a digression from your question as asked. Could you please confirm that an answer with the documentation link clarifying the overload issue would fully address the question as asked so I could write it up? Or, if not, [edit] the question to clarify?

With the help of @jcalz I managed to find the solution to my problem.
Unfortunately, as mentioned in the docs it is not possible to make subscribe fully infer types of the overloaded methods, so it will not support, for example, built-in event targets, such as process.on('warning', ...).
However, it is possible to support the targets that implement specific interface such as:
interface Target<E extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>> {
  on<N extends Extract<keyof E, string>>(name: N, handler: E[N]): void;
}

From here, we could create the subscribe function that would look the following:
const subscribe = <
    EventMap extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>,
    Name extends Extract<keyof EventMap, string>,
  >(
    name: Name,
    handler: EventMap[Name],
    target: Target<EventMap>
  ) => { target.on(name, handler); };

We can even go further and make Target a class, so others can reuse it without reimplementing the functionality:
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

class Target<E extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>> {
  // Note: storing map type is required to make type inference work 
  // See here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55887088/24446449
  private _map: E | undefined;
  private _eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  on<N extends Extract<keyof E, string>>(name: N, handler: E[N]): void {
    this._eventEmitter.on(name, handler)
  }
}

Here is the full example code:
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

const subscribe = <
    EventMap extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>,
    Name extends Extract<keyof EventMap, string>,
  >(
    name: Name,
    handler: EventMap[Name],
    target: Target<EventMap>
  ) => { target.on(name, handler); };

class Target<E extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>> {
  // Note: storing map type is required to make type inference work 
  // See here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55887088/24446449
  private _map: E | undefined;
  private _eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  on<N extends Extract<keyof E, string>>(name: N, handler: E[N]): void {
    this._eventEmitter.on(name, handler)
  }
}

type TestEventMap = {
  a: (a1: string) => void;
  b: (b1: number) => void;
}

class Test extends Target<TestEventMap> {}

const test = new Test();

subscribe('a', (a1) => console.log(a1), test);
//              ^
//              inferred type: string
subscribe('b', (b1) => console.log(b1), test); 
//              ^
//              inferred type: number


Uh, so you wrote and accepted your own answer without responding to my last comment? It is your prerogative to do this, but I would have strongly preferred writing up my own answer. As it is, you've solved a problem not mentioned in your question. Refactoring from overloads to generics is reasonable, but out of scope for your question as asked.

I apologise if there were any misunderstandings, but it seemed to me that you already provided the answer in the comment above: "You can't do this". I do not see a point in editing the question as your answer is a valuable knowledge for those in doubt. However, once you evaluated the possibility as "not directly, in my experience" possible, I decided to try it out myself, crediting your initial thoughts in the answer. In the end, it is a collaboration, not a competition, and providing a workaround seems more helpful to me than just simply saying "no" to the question.

You are of course more than welcome to provide your own solution to the problem. Me personally and the viewers will only benefit from seeing other points of view.
